# 4.1.2. Hartl rails tutorial. Why "def full_title(page_title = '')" and not just "def full_title(page_title)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Helper goes like:

```js
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      page_title + " | " + base_title
    end
  end
end
```

I don't understand why there is "page_title = ' ' " instead of just argument "page_title"

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is default value. When calling `full_title` if you not pass `page_title` it will take `default '' - blank string`

Answer (score 1):

It is meant to display the usage of default values in arguments.

In this case, it is not needed because there is code to deal with the case of empty or nil argument.